# request cart_obj in template tag filter Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Is it possible to add a cart_obj request in a Django Template filter

I currently have in my template tag:

```
@register.filter
def existing_product(product):
    return CartItem.objects.filter(item_id=product.id).exists()
```

and in my template:

```
{% if product|existing_product %}

    {% endif %}
```

the only problem is that this filter only finds the item_id that is equal to the product.id , I want to be able to add an additional filter that looks for the item_id in the cart_obj.

views.py

```
cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
```

basically my template tag would be something like:

```
return CartItem.objects.filter(item_id=product.id, items_cart_id=cart_obj).exists()
```

with the addition of filtering the 'items_cart_id', but I'm not sure how to do this and what to put in the template 'if' condition.

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    item        = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    items_cart  = models.ForeignKey('Cart', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'item:{} cart:{} quantity:{}'.format(self.item, self.items_cart, self.quantity)


class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)  
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: could you please describe well what you actually want to achieve? I think its pretty easy to do but im not quite sure what you plan to do here

Comment: I want to check whether a product exists inside the users cart , if so then show a remove button otherwise show an add to cart button,  currently the filter I have checks if the product exists regardless of the user.  I'm using a template tag but don't know how to add this cart_obj request inside of that filter.

Comment: Can you present your cart-to-user assignment mechanism (if its connected to session or just staright up connected). It will help me present an answer

Comment: i've added the cartmanager model

Comment: Plase attach your `Cart` and `CartItem` models as well I can't really see the relation type between Cart and CartItem so please just paste them here. I can see you started Django a few months ago but it still needs some polishing.

Comment: yes i've added the 2 models

Answer (score 0):

The code to check if the current item (DetailView) is in the user's cart will look something like this.
on your `User` model add a method (or `Cart` if you dont want to mess with built-in `User`)

```
class Cart(...):
...

def contains_item(self, item):
    # check if there exists a CartItem 
    # instance that hold a relation with given item
    return self.cart_item_set().filter(item=item).exists()
```

so this will return if the given item is in a given cart so your templatetag should look like this

```
@register.filter
def contains_item(cart, product):
    return cart.contains_item(product)
```

and call it in the template like

```
{{ cart_obj|contains_item:product }}
```

Comment: I tried this but it comes back with error: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'has_in_cart'

Comment: is it possible in the template to do something like {% if product|existing_product with cart_obj %} , i know this doesn't work but how can i add the additional cart_obj to the if statement, if possible ?

Comment: @mac95782 well no wonder -  this is just an example for the code just add `if not user.is_authenticated(): return False`  to the filter - stack is not "please do it for me and i will copy paste it" think for youself and read the docs

Comment: @mac95782 and to answer your question no its not possible here - this is not even how the with statement works in python.  To do it "your way" do it as in answer edit

Comment: Thanks for your efforts , It still has some fixing to do , but i will read more into this 